# How share permissions affected while migrating

Tags: migration, storage-area-network, network-attached-storage

We 'll be migrating the data  from NS704G(memphis) to NS480(in dallas). My question is,how the  access and share  permissions  the users 've in Memphis location 'd be effected once the migration is going on. Would all the access be replicated to the new celerra as it is ?Because , we have a security team handling the access rights on NAS and according to them there's no  tool available to  replicate the share permission and this needs to be done individually.

I  will appreciate if someone can elaborate this to help me understand this better.

Besides, Can i create a new share in my celerra NS480 located in Dallas and ask the other team to transfer the permissions, say from nas6/urs21$, to my newly created share and see if it works...

Pointers are welcome..Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [SecureCopy](http://www.scriptlogic.com/products/securecopy/). It copies file permissions and share permissions.